# Sass unhandled error event

Tags: css, sass

I have a sass file which I want to process. A snippet of the file is:

```
@media {
  .tabs {
      @extend .uppercase;
      background-color: $light;
      border-top: 2px solid $stable;
  }
}
```

When running the gulp file I get the following error:

```
Error: media query expression must begin with '('
    on line 173 of scss/style_common.scss
```

If I remove the portion, everything runs ok, the css is generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@media rules need an expression to go along with it, something like:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .tabs {
      @extend .uppercase;
      background-color: $light;
      border-top: 2px solid $stable;
  }
}
```

The error it's giving you is indicating you are missing the expression part.

see more examples from [mozilla's @media docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).